# fetch json data from top to bottom using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, fetch

I am trying to fetch json data from top to bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    const finalResult = {};
    const data = {
        "data": [
          {
            "persons": {
              "Dupont nicolas": "President",
              "George frimaolo": "engineer",
              "Tiprana masilo": "football player"
            }
          },
          {
            "persons": {
              "Balack martini": "author",
              "Dupont nicolas": "Student",
              "Joseph Allen": "dentist"
            }
          },
          {
            "persons": {
              "Fred Samanta": "baker",
              "Romero flagipi": "actor",
              "Fred Samanta": "astronaut",
              "Joseph Allen": "pilot",
              "Anne Hedley": "teacher"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    
    for (let i in data.data) {
      for (let j in data.data[i].persons) {
        finalResult[j] = finalResult[j] ? finalResult[j] : data.data[i].persons[j];
      }
    }
    
    console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: Like that we are getting data from bottom to top ! but I need it in the opposite sense (from top to bottom)

Comment: No, it's only because "Dupont nicolas" is called two times. I get your data from top to bottom.

Comment: yes that's the point , when it called two (or many) times we should get the first one

Comment: Fred Samanta is called two times in the same `Object`, which makes your `JSON` invalid, it will be overwritten in JS.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Array.reduce` should accomplish your goal.

```js
const obj = {
  // json data shown in your question
}

const result = obj.data.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => ({
    ...cur.persons,
    ...acc,
  }),
  {}
);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I need it in the opposite sense ,  from top to bottom

Comment: Not sure I understand.  The output from my answer gives the same result as you posted in your question.  The keys might be in different order but the resulting object contains the correct values according to your question.  Could you clarify your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and `Object.assign`

```js
const combine = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, { persons }) => Object.assign(acc, persons), {});

const data = [
  {
    persons: {
      "Dupont nicolas": "President",
      "George frimaolo": "engineer",
      "Tiprana masilo": "football player",
    },
  },
  {
    persons: {
      "Balack martini": "author",
      "Dupont nicolas": "Student",
      "Joseph Allen": "dentist",
    },
  },
  {
    persons: {
      "Fred Samanta": "baker",
      "Romero flagipi": "actor",
      "Fred Samanta": "astronaut",
      "Joseph Allen": "pilot",
      "Anne Hedley": "teacher",
    },
  },
];

console.log(combine(data))
```